# Antd dropdown hover issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using `DropDown` from [ant desing library](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) and looping over `DropDown` for an array.
The hover action is working fine for only last item.
The code is as below:
here `catNavItems` is an `array`. e.g. `['Furniture', 'Cushions', 'Blankets']`

```
{_.map(catNavItems, function(item, key){
            return <Dropdown
                    overlayClassName="shop-navigation cat-nav"
                    overlay={catMenu}
                    trigger={["hover"]}
                    onVisibleChange={() => handleVisibleChangeCat(!catNavVisible, item)}
                    getPopupContainer={(trigger) => trigger.parentElement}
                    visible={catNavVisible}
                    overlayStyle={{ width: "100%", cursor: "pointer" }}
                  >
                    <div
                      className={
                        catNavColor
                          ? "shop my-account-header qa-cursor qa-hover"
                          : "shop my-account-header qa-cursor"
                      }
                      style={{
                        verticalAlign: "middle",
                        marginLeft: "20px",
                        marginRight: "20px",
                        height: "40px",
                        lineHeight: "40px",
                      }}
                      // onClick={() => {
                      //   router.push("/products/all-categories");
                      // }}
                    >
                      {item}
                    </div>
                  </Dropdown>
          })}
```

Please suggest if anyone can help here.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you create codesandbox?

Comment: Can you also post CSS class where you added hover.

Comment: @Nemanja : Not able to do that.